# stuck at cdn.sstatic.net

Tags: bug, status-norepro, cdn, page-load

I can't open any page on stackoverflow.com from about an hour ago.

Whenever I open any url starting with `http://www.stackoverflow.com/..`, My browser starts getting response quickly and Title is shown withing `1-3 sec`. But it just stop further loading. Even for too much time. Here it stucks

[image: capture]

Comment: No problems here. Try flushing your browser cache and DNS cache.

Comment: cache already cleared. Also tried it in diff browsers. How to clear DNS chache..?

Comment: On Windows, open a Command prompt window and type `ipconfig /flushdns`.

Comment: didn't help :-(

Comment: `i.stack.imgur.com` is also inaccessible here. It just keep loading. Do u see the capture I have attached in this question. It does not load here. Waiting and waiting.. from which corner you r @Mooseman..?

Comment: I see the screenshot. From the book of general internet troubleshooting... did you reset your modem?

Comment: Surprised. Disconnecting and connection again WORKED.. oh no I don't understand it. Thnx @Mooseman

Comment: Great. Added as an answer.

Comment: Who is your ISP?

Comment: It is `Idea Cellular`.

Comment: We're seeing a very similar issue, and it only occurs with IPv6 enabled. I believe this question relates to it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186306/problems-with-css-delivery-via-ipv6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the book of general internet troubleshooting... did you reset your modem?

Comment: +1'd and accepted. It would be better if it can be little more informative

Comment: @ShashwatTripathi - this isn't something *we* can do anything about though, this entirely a connectivity issue unrelated to our sites.