# Stack Exchange Page Formatting Goes weird

Tags: support, bug, design

For reasons I don't understand, the page formatting goes weird when I look at various stack exchange sites.

The error is not consistent.  It comes and goes as it pleases, depending on factors I have not yet been able to identify or isolate.

Even more weird, is if I try to change the profile. I get this/these errors...

`Oops! There was a problem updating your profile:`

`unusual error updating your profile -- please try again!`

So far, this site (meta.stackoverflow.com) and the regular stackoverflow.com do not exhibit this behavior. Most of my other StackExchange sites do this; when they feel like it.

Did I do something wrong ? Is this my problem ? Is it the system ? Has anyone else observed this or similar behavior ?

This is what the page looks like

[image]

Comment: You're missing the CSS - something to do with sstatic.net most likely

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185136/stackoverflow-static-assets-not-loading http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/188785/stack-exchange-sites-not-rendering-static-assets-correctly http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/186306/problems-with-css-delivery-via-ipv6 http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191788/cdn-sstatic-net-is-having-me-stare-at-a-plain-white-browser And several of those list even more duplicates. How many people are going to report this issue over and over again without searching for other people experiencing the same issue?

Comment: If you say it's a duplicate of one of those, okay. I looked in the list of similar questions and didn't see anything that even looked close.  Thank you for pointing to duplicates, if they are, as you say, duplicates.

Comment: @Doorknob, is there something I can do to fix this ?

Comment: They won't all be duplicates of your *cause* but they are all duplicates of the *symptom*. You'll need to look at them and see the various responses, since one fix worked for some people, another fix worked for others, etc.